# Java Swing File Organization

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, methods, filewriter

I want to write to a txt file by pressing JButton.I want to write JTextField.getText() to a txt file by pressing JButton. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4d7d3.png)
What should I do in general.

I tried to write FileWriter class but didn't actually get it.

Comment: You're asking a question about multiple steps, but you have not shown what you've tried nor have you told us which step you're stuck on. If you state, "all of them", then perhaps you're here too soon with this question and might want to try to solve this yourself first.  Then if still stuck, show your code and ask your more specific and site-appropriate question For best results on this site, please check out the [ask], [tour] and [help] links.

Comment: Also, have a look at the [Swing Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html), in particular, the sections on using ActionListeners with JButtons and the use of JTextFields. Also, the main Java tutorials can help you with File I&O, all information needed to solve this problem.

Comment: *"What should I do in general."* - In general ... break down complex tasks into simpler ones.  For example 1) work out how to do something in response to a button press, 2) work out how to get the text from a text box (e.g. as a string),  3) work out how to save some text (e.g. a string) to a file.